# hide the message "We don't have as many "ProductName" as you requested" when Product is already Present in cart

Tags: magento-2.1

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Add a new product. set it's quantity to 1.
2. Add the product to cart from product page.
3. Go back again to product page and add the same product to cart again.

**What Happens now?**

I get the message "We don't have as many "Product Name" as you requested."

**What I want to happen?**

If product is already Present in cart, it should not display this message and get redirected to cart when we press "Add to cart" button.

**What I've tried till now !**

In the file `vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/StockStateProvider.php`, if I comment the following block of code

```
if (!$this->checkQty($stockItem, $summaryQty) || !$this->checkQty($stockItem, $qty)) {
            $message = __('We don\'t have as many "%1" as you requested.', $stockItem->getProductName());
            $result->setHasError(true)->setMessage($message)->setQuoteMessage($message)->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
            return $result;
        } else {
```

the message is not displayed and I get redirected to cart page, but the number of items in the minicart is incremented. It becomes [image] instead of 1.

So, my question is what is the best way to achieve this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Any solution on this?